# how to automatic resize dhtmlxgrid on different monitor screens

Tags: jquery, html, grid, autoresize, dhtmlx

I am using DHTMLX grid that has been set side by side within a table as that was the only way I seem to have gotten them to go that way.

I would like to get the grids to somehow automatic size when it is on a specific size monitor as I currently can't seem to figure out how to. It works on the smaller screens that some of our clients have but on the bigger monitors they have a larger open space which doesn't look good.
My code goes as follows:

Html:

```
     <table class="table tblExp ">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Business</th>
                                <th>Personal</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td >
                                <div id="grdBusExp" style= "width:100%;;height:400px;"></div> 
                                <div class="btnBusGrp">
                                    <button class="btn btn-primary" id ="newBusiness" onclick ="addNewBusiness()">Add Expense </button>
                                    <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="busExpGrd.deleteSelectedItem()">Delete Expense</button>
                                    </div>
                            </td>
                            <td><div id="grdPrslExp" style="width:100%;height:400px;overflow:auto;"></div>
                                <div class="btnpersGrp">
                                <button class="btn btn-primary" id="newPersonal" onclick="addNewPersonal()">Add Expense</button>
                                <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="prlsExpGrd.deleteSelectedItem()">Delete Expense</button>
                                    </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>  
                            </tbody> 
                    </table> 

the grids:

    busExpGrd = new dhtmlXGridObject('grdBusExp');
                busExpGrd.setStyle("background:#7db9e8;color:white;");
                busExpGrd.setImagePath("/codebase36/imgs/");
                busExpGrd.setHeader("Id,CMAID,P_B,Description,Amount");
                busExpGrd.setInitWidths("50,50,5,375,230");
                busExpGrd.enableAutoWidth(true, 882, 500);
                busExpGrd.setColAlign("center,center,left,left,left");
                busExpGrd.setColTypes("ed,ed,ed,ed,ed");
                busExpGrd.setColSorting("int,int,str,str,str");
                busExpGrd.enableAutoWidth(true);
                busExpGrd.enableEditEvents(false, true, false);
                busExpGrd.attachEvent("onEditCell", editBusiness);
                busExpGrd.attachEvent("onSubAjaxLoad", addNewBusiness);
                busExpGrd.attachEvent("onBeforeRowDeleted", deleteBusiness);
                busExpGrd.setCustomSorting(sort_custom, 1);
                busExpGrd.csv.cell = "|";
                busExpGrd.csv.row = "$";
                busExpGrd.setColumnHidden(0, true);
                busExpGrd.setColumnHidden(1, true);
                busExpGrd.setColumnHidden(2, true);
                busExpGrd.init();
                busExpGrd.attachFooter("TOTAL,#cspan,#cspan,#cspan,{#stat_total}", ["font-weight:bold;", "", "", "", "font-weight:bold;"]);

prlsExpGrd = new dhtmlXGridObject('grdPrslExp');
            prlsExpGrd.setImagePath("/codebase36/imgs/");
            prlsExpGrd.setStyle("background:#7db9e8;color:white;");
            prlsExpGrd.setHeader("Id,CMAID,P_B,Description, Amount");
            prlsExpGrd.setInitWidths("50,50,5,375,230");
            prlsExpGrd.enableAutoWidth(true, 1000, 500);
            prlsExpGrd.setColAlign("left,left,left,left,left");
            prlsExpGrd.setColTypes("ed,ed,ed,ed,ed");
            prlsExpGrd.setColSorting("int,int,str,str,str");
            prlsExpGrd.enableAutoWidth(true);
            prlsExpGrd.enableEditTabOnly(true);
            prlsExpGrd.enableEditEvents(false, true, false);
            prlsExpGrd.attachEvent("onEditCell", editPersonal);
            prlsExpGrd.attachEvent("onSubAjaxLoad", addNewPersonal);
            prlsExpGrd.attachEvent("onBeforeRowDeleted", deleteBusiness);
            prlsExpGrd.setCustomSorting(sort_custom, 1);
            prlsExpGrd.csv.cell = "|";
            prlsExpGrd.csv.row = "$";
            prlsExpGrd.setColumnHidden(0, true);
            prlsExpGrd.setColumnHidden(1, true);
            prlsExpGrd.setColumnHidden(2, true);
            prlsExpGrd.init();
            prlsExpGrd.attachFooter("TOTAL,#cspan,#cspan,#cspan,{#stat_total}", ["font-weight:bold;", "", "", "", "font-weight:bold;"]);
```

is there something I am missing or do I have to programeticly set it?

Answer (score 2):

Use [setInitWidthsP](http://docs.dhtmlx.com/api__dhtmlxgrid_setinitwidthsp.html) function to set grid width in percentage. This will automatically expands grid columns on larger screens.